# add groupby to existing dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df  
date    firm    fruit   type  mean     occurences
0   2010-01-05  banana  low 0.380949    1    
0   2010-01-05  apple   low 0.380949    1
```

How could I add the positive share? I tried:

```
df['daily_count_by_date_fruit'] = df.groupby(['date','fruit'])['occurences'].transform('count')
df['positive_share'] = df['occurences']/df['daily_count_by_date_fruitB']
```

Expected Output:

```
date    firm    fruit   type       mean    occurences  daily_count_by_date_fruit    positive_share
0   2010-01-05  banana  positive 0.280949   3             4                             0.75
0   2010-01-05  banana  high     0.280949   1             4                             0.75
```

Comment: Share representative sample of `df` dataset and result You are expecting to obtain please.

Comment: your occurences column has changed. any reason why?

Comment: thought it made more sense to call it that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my understanding of the problem, here is a solution to solve it:

```py
# Build sample dataframe
d = {'date': ['2010-01-05', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-05'], 
     'fruit': ['banana', 'apple', 'banana', 'apple'], 
     'occurences': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Build function that counts fruit occurrences by date
def daily_count_by_date_fruit(line, df):
    fruit = line['fruit']
    date = line['date']
    return df[['date', 'fruit', 'occurences']][(df['fruit']==fruit) & (df['date']==date)]\
        .groupby(['date', 'fruit'], as_index=False)\
        .sum()\
        .iloc[0,2]

# Calculate fruit occurrences by date
df['daily_count_by_date_fruit'] = df[['date', 'fruit']].apply(lambda x: daily_count_by_date_fruit(x, df), axis=1)

# Calculate positive share
df['positive_share'] = df['occurences']/df['daily_count_by_date_fruit']
```

Here is my output:

```
    date    fruit   occurences  daily_count_by_date_fruit   positive_share
0   2010-01-05  banana  1   4   0.250000
1   2010-01-05  apple   2   6   0.333333
2   2010-01-05  banana  3   4   0.750000
3   2010-01-05  apple   4   6   0.666667
```

Good luck